# Mercurial bookmark delete does not propagate

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a bookmark which is already synchronized with the remote server. Several colleagues have clones of that repository including the bookmark.
I am deleting and pushing the bookmark with the following commands:

```
$hg bookmarks --delete myBookmark
$hg push -B myBookmark
```

I am checking if the bookmark still exists on the remote server, and it doesn't:

```
$hg incoming -B
searching for changed bookmarks
no changed bookmarks found
```

So, all in all it seems that the bookmark has been deleted. Still, my colleagues, after pulling, they still have the bookmark. It's true that it does not move forward with my future pushes to default branch, but it still exist. I guess that they also have to run the command **hg bookmarks --delete myBookmark** in order to get rid of it.

Is this normal behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this normal behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Yes, this is normal.  Your colleagues' bookmarks will not be pushed back to the server unless they request it (with `hg push -B`), but neither will the server's lack-of-a-bookmark get pulled.  This is a Good Thing, because your colleagues may still be using the bookmark even if you aren't.

Comment: Great answer. Exactly what I wanted to know.